# Minimal restrictions to generate Arbitrary in range

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck

I would like to generate Arbitrary value for ordered tree-like structure whose type is, say

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

A function that inserts value into this tree while keeping it ordered would require that value should be Ord. But to generate ordered Trees for Arbitrary instance I would need to generate value in range "[low,hi]" and Ord is insufficient for that. So I also required that value is Enum since Enum allows getting  values from given boundary. The `choose` below also requires  System.Random.Random:

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary
import System.Random

generateTree :: (Arbitrary a, Ord a, Enum a, Random a) => a -> a -> Gen (Tree a)
generateTree l u = do
  genLeaf <- arbitrary
  if genLeaf
    then return Leaf
    else do
      x <- choose (l, u)
      left <- generateTree l (pred x)
      right <- generateTree (succ x) u
      return $ Node left x right
```

So to use this for `arbitrary` implementation I should require the same classes in Arbitrary class:

```
instance (Arbitrary a, Ord a, Enum a, Rand.Random a) => Arbitrary (Tree a) where
  arbitrary = do
    l <- arbitrary
    u <- arbitrary
    generateTree l u
```

Here, while requirement `Ord a => Tree a` is enough for data structure itself, I require `(Arbitrary a, Ord a, Enum a, Rand.Random a) => Tree a` for it's generator. It looks like leaking implementation details into declaration - probably I look at this wrong way, I am learning Haskell. But still there are questions:

1. Is there a way to declare more generic generator that does not have as much requirements?
2. Is there a way to declare other instance for `Arbitrary (Tree a)` along with one above that would have different set of requirements, something like `Arbitrary (Tree Int)` that would be used for `Int`s only?

Comment: You can generate the trees by arbitrary operations on the tree. This  only requires an `Arbitrary` instance for `a` and doesn't require access to the implementation of those operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want arbitrary *ordered* trees, there is no way to get rid of the `Ord a` constraint in the `Arbitrary (Tree a)` instance. However, you don't need `Enum` or `Random` (recall that `Arbitrary` is doing random value generation - so naturally you shouldn't need Random as well).

Here is how I would implement the Arbitrary instance.

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Gen
import Test.QuickCheck

arbitraryTree :: (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Gen (Tree a)
arbitraryTree = do 
  x <- arbitrary 
  y <- suchThat arbitrary (>= x) 
  go x y 
   where 
    go mn mx = frequency [(1, return Leaf), (1, arbNode)] where

      arbNode = do 
        a <- suchThat arbitrary (\x -> x >= mn && x <= mx)
        l <- go mn a
        r <- go a mx 
        return (Node l a r) 

instance (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Tree a) where 
  arbitrary = arbitraryTree
```

Note that you could make this more reliable by using `suchThatMaybe` and supplying a default value if no suitable value in the range can be found within a certain amount of tries.

As for your second question, you can indeed have the following instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Arbitrary (Tree a)
instance Arbitrary (Tree Int)
```

and the compiler will select the `Tree a` instance only if `a` is not `Int`. However, I would advise against this - if you are mainly interested in testing `Tree Int` or even a small set of `Tree` types, just have instances for those types - no general instance for `Tree a`.

---

As an aside, the generator I gave above is not very good - it generates a `Leaf` exactly half the time. In principle, I would like a generator for a type like this to always generate "medium" sized trees. A simple way to implement this is to have a high probability of generating a `Node` initially, and decrease that probability steadily as the tree grows:

```
arbitraryTree :: (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Float -> Float -> Gen (Tree a)
arbitraryTree c' f = do 
  x <- arbitrary 
  y <- suchThat arbitrary (>= x) 
  go x y c' 
   where 
    go mn mx c = frequency [(1000-q, return Leaf), (q, arbNode)] where
      q = round (1000 * c)

      arbNode = do 
        a <- suchThat arbitrary (\x -> x >= mn && x <= mx)
        l <- go mn a (c * f) 
        r <- go a mx (c * f) 
        return (Node l a r) 

instance (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Tree a) where 
  arbitrary = arbitraryTree 0.9 0.9
```

You can play around with the parameters to `arbitraryTree` to get trees that you like.

Comment: I see that suchThat is not very effective since it tries all available values until finds suitable one. That seems the cost of removing assumptions, acceptable for tests though.